# Android: main app and module installed later

Tags: java, android, google-play, apk-expansion-files

Is it possible to have an Android app made up of two parts:

a main part and a module that can be installed by the user or by the app itself?

I mean a module like a part of the application, including activities that in the end are as they were compiled together, or something similar.

I read something about the expansion file (and apk expansion file) that could be a module of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done now with Dynamic Feature modules:  https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/on-demand-delivery